# Height Conversion - cm to feet and inches (and vice versa)

Tags: java, android

I have an edit text in which the user can enter his height in centimeters as well as in feet+inches, eg. 5'11". I have a toggle button for the target unit, so I want that when the user selects centimeters, it should convert the entered text from feet+inches into centimeters, and vice versa.
  Now when I am converting the height to centimeters it's adding "\"" at  the end. I think it's because of the text watcher I have put which add "\"" at the end when count is reaching to 3.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnCm:
            toggleHeightButton(R.id.btnCm,R.id.btnFeet,false);
            convertToCentimeter(enter_height);
            break;
        case R.id.btnFeet:
            toggleHeightButton(R.id.btnFeet,R.id.btnCm,true);
            enter_height.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(enter_height));
            break;
        case R.id.btnKg:
            toggleweightButton(R.id.btnKg,R.id.btnpound,false);
            break;
        case R.id.btnpound:
            toggleweightButton(R.id.btnpound,R.id.btnKg,true);
            break;
    }
}

public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText enter_height) {
        mEditText = enter_height;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int count = s.length();
        String str = s.toString();
        if (count == 1) {
            str = str + "'";
        } else if (count == 2) {
            return;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            str = str + "\"";
        } else if ((count > 4) && (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != '\"') ){
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + "\"";
        } else {
            return;
        }

        mEditText.setText(str);
        mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with regular expressions, but I think you should try the more straightforward way first.

Basically, the format is like `xx'xx"`. We can `split` the string using the `'` deliminator. That way, the first item of the array is the number of feet.

Then, we have the second item of the split string left: `xx"`. For this, we just need to substring it to remove the last character and then we can get the number of inches!

Try to write the code yourself!

---

If you're really stuck, here's the solution:

```
String str = s.toString();
String[] splitString = str.split("'");
String firstItem = splitString[0];
try {
    int feet = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(firstItem);
    String secondPart = splitString[1].substring(0, splitString[1].length() - 1);
    int inches = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(secondPart);
    // YAY! you got your feet and inches!
    System.out.println(feet);
    System.out.println(inches);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return;
}
```

And here's a solution using regex:

```
String str = s.toString();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)'((\\d+)\")?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    return;
}

int feet = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(matcher.group(1));
String inchesStr = matcher.group(3);
int inches = 0;
if (inchesStr != null) {
    inches = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(inchesStr);
}

// YAY! you got your feet and inches!
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a mathematic calculation to manage centimeter to feet and vice versa conversion.

```
public static String feetToCentimeter(String feet){
        double dCentimeter = 0d;
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(feet)){
            if(feet.contains("'")){
                String tempfeet = feet.substring(0, feet.indexOf("'"));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tempfeet)){
                    dCentimeter += ((Double.valueOf(tempfeet))*30.48);
                }
            }if(feet.contains("\"")){
                String tempinch = feet.substring(feet.indexOf("'")+1, feet.indexOf("\""));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tempinch)){
                    dCentimeter += ((Double.valueOf(tempinch))*2.54);
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(dCentimeter);
        //Format to decimal digit as per your requirement
    }

    public static String centimeterToFeet(String centemeter) {
        int feetPart = 0;
        int inchesPart = 0;
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(centemeter)) {
            double dCentimeter = Double.valueOf(centemeter);
            feetPart = (int) Math.floor((dCentimeter / 2.54) / 12);
            System.out.println((dCentimeter / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
            inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((dCentimeter / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
        }
        return String.format("%d' %d''", feetPart, inchesPart);
    }
```

Comment: `centimeterToFeet` is not working if `dCentimeter` = 91.44 , 182.88 etc.